# Basic painting code. It doesn't work

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, draw, paint

I'm trying to draw a Rectangle inside a JPanel inside a MainPanel inside a JFrame.
In the Main Class I initialize a RoomView:

```
roomView = new RoomView(newropc,"Default");
```

And then I execute:

```
private void init_panels() {
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(toolsPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainPanel.add(roomView,BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainPanel.add(libraryPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```

Then The class roomview executes:

```
public class RoomView extends JPanel{
    private RoomPController rpc;
    private double w, h;
    int qFactor;
    Vector v;
    String roomName;
    DrawingPanelVector dpv;


public RoomView(RoomPController newRpc, String newRoomName) {
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,350));
    rpc = newRpc;
w = 0;
h = 0;
qFactor = 1;
v = new Vector();
roomName = newRoomName;
    v.add(new GraphicRectangle(0, 0, (int)(w*qFactor), (int)(h*qFactor), Color.black));
    dpv = new DrawingPanelVector(v);
    add(dpv);
    setVisible(true);
    getPreferredSize();
}

public void RepaintRoom() {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    v = new Vector();
    w = rpc.getRoomW(roomName);
    h = rpc.getRoomL(roomName);
    System.out.println("Room w = " + w + " Room h = " + h);
    System.out.println("Height = " + getHeight() + " Width = " + getWidth());
    if ((double)getHeight()/h < (double)getWidth()/w) qFactor = (int)((double)getHeight()/h);
    else qFactor = (int)((double)getWidth()/w);
    System.out.println("qFactor = " + qFactor);
    v.add(new GraphicRectangle(0, 0, (int)(w*qFactor), (int)(h*qFactor), Color.black));
    dpv = new DrawingPanelVector(v);
    add(dpv);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

AND, FINALLY, DrawingPanelVector is:

```
public class DrawingPanelVector extends JPanel {
    // variable miembro
    private Vector v;
    // constructor
    public DrawingPanelVector(Vector va) {
        super(new FlowLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,350));
        v = va;
        getPreferredSize();
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Drawable dib;
        Iterator it;
        it = v.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
        dib = (Drawable) it.next();
        dib.draw(g);
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't do anything and nothing appears on the MainPanel.
It's driving me mad and I have to give this code working to my teacher in 7 hours.

Comment: Custom painting should be done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method not the paint() method. Don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...);

Comment: Where do I have to put that super.paintComponent(...) method? @camickr

Comment: @user2211939 You don't "put" it anywhere.  You should be overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and within that method (it should mostly be the first call), you call `super.paintComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem, as I see it is...

You call...

```
roomView = new RoomView(newropc,"Default");
```

Which calls...

```
public RoomView(RoomPController newRpc, String newRoomName) {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,350));
    rpc = newRpc;
    w = 0;
    h = 0;
    qFactor = 1;
    v = new Vector();
    roomName = newRoomName;
    getPreferredSize();
}
```

Which adds nothing to the component.  There is no `DrawingPaneVector` added to your `RoomView`, meaning that nothing will be painted...

**Additional**

You are violating the paint chain.  The paint process is a complex system, involving a number of sub methods and delegation.  By overriding the `paint` method and failing to call `super.paint` you've circumvented the entire painting process.

Instead, you should be overriding `paintComponent` and ensuring you are calling `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the work the `paintComponent` needs to do gets done...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Drawable dib;
    Iterator it;
    it = v.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        dib = (Drawable) it.next();
        dib.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

The use of `setPreferredSize` is discouraged, the main problem is that this could easily be changed by another part of your program.  Instead, you should be overriding `getPreferredSize` of the custom component.

**More Additional**

I'd suggest dropping the use of `Vector` and instead use `List`, instantiating a implementation of `ArrayList`.  The only benefit of `Vector` is the fact that it is `synchronized`, but I can't see any reason why you want this.

I'd also suggest taking a read through [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  This will make your life easier in the long wrong, as you won't need to cast objects.

A possible implementation of your `DrawingPanelVector` panel using `List` and generics...

```
public class DrawingPanelVector extends JPanel {

    private List<Drawable> drawables;

    public DrawingPanelVector() {
        drawables = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void add(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.add(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600, 350);
    }

    // redefinición del método paint()
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MadProgrammer, I appreciate your help very much, really
So, I finally wrote this, I'll edit my post with the changes I've made
it doesn't work, though

Comment: With out a reference to `Drawable` or `GraphicRectangle` it's difficult to say exactly, but having had a quick look, I would take a closer look at `new GraphicRectangle(0, 0, (int)(w*qFactor), (int)(h*qFactor), Color.black)`, because if I'm not mistaken, `0 * 1 = 0`...

Comment: You're not mistaken..I had a wrong idea of which methods were executed once I created a DrawingPanelVector. Besides, how do I add something to the DrawingPanelVector with your implementation once I've created it? It still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm not...I'm just tired.

Comment: IT WORKS! IT DOES WORK!
I don't know how, but it works! I'll try to understand the hole thing now
Thank you very very much, really
Is there anything I can do to thank you apart from clicking the green tick of your answer?

Comment: Nice to see it work ;) - Accepting the answer would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation
I'm sorry dude...I'm a newbie
but you can say you've done your good-action-of-the-day

Comment: Nice to have helped some one :D